# Only index.php working in magento site, how to tackle this?

Tags: php, magento, iis

i had created a magento store in local by iis. But only index.php file or home page is working.other pages are not opened.

Here is my error generate in chrome

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002
Requested URL   http://scannerbattery.net:80/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3NjYW5uZXJiYXR0ZXJ5Lm5ldC9pbmRleC5waHA,/product/556/
Physical Path   E:\Sanjay\ScannerBattery\checkout\cart\add\uenc\aHR0cDovL3NjYW5uZXJiYXR0ZXJ5Lm5ldC9pbmRleC5waHA,\product\556\
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

So please suggest where i can be wrong

Please help.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: this may help you http://invosoft.co.uk/post/2011/07/20/Installing-Magento-eCommerce-on-Windows-and-IIS-7.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento uses it's own URL routing system, so the web server must somehow pass all requests except for static to this system. Commonly you need to use some URL rewriting method of your web server.

IIS can be configured using `web.config` file in the application directory. You can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <rewrite> 
            <rules> 
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1” stopProcessing="true"> 
                    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false"/> 
                    <conditions> 
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" /> 
                </rule> 
            </rules> 
        </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

You need to install UrlRewrite IIS module to use this config.

Answer (score -1):

Check if .htaccess file exists and it's allowed in your hosts settings.

Comment: Please read the question properly, the user is using iis server and not apache

Comment: Sory. In that case look at ISAPIRewrite or check/configure your own rewrite module.